# Doctrine - extended entity that uses fields of parent entity as its own

Tags: inheritance, doctrine-orm, entity, extends

I'm trying to find the best solution for a common situation (all examples are simplified).

**INTRO**

I have a `Record` entity that holds `name` field:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Record
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100);
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return Record
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
}
```

And `RecordFile` entity that has its own `filename` field:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class RecordFile
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=200);
     */
    protected $filename;

    /**
     * Set filename
     *
     * @param string $filename
     *
     * @return RecordFile
     */
    public function setFilename($filename)
    {
        $this->filename = $filename;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get filename
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFilename()
    {
        return $this->filename;
    }
}
```

**PROBLEM**

I want to make processing as follows - create `Record` entity, set fields, persist it, and than extract `RecordFile` entity with extended getters that operate on `Record` fields.

```
// Record #1
$record = (new Record())
    ->setName('Test')
;

$em->persist($record);
$em->flush();

$recordFile = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:RecordFile')->find(1);

// Returns formatted 'name' field
$recordFile->getName();
```

`RecordFile` should use `name` field (basically, any field) of the `Record` entity and format it for some purposes.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class RecordFile
{
    // ---

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->formatNameField($this->name);
    }

    // ---
}
```

This `RecordFile` should in some way extend `Record` base class, to overwrite it's getters methods, but should still has its own fields and access to the "base" `Record` entity fields.

**TRIED SOLUTIONS**

1) Doctrine STI CTI ([Inheritance mapping documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html)) - but those mappings strictly separate the data, which I basically need in one row.

2) One-To-Many between `Record` and `RecordFile` - where record file has custom getters such as:

```
    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->formatNameField($this->record->name);
    }
```

But it feels kind of hackish, without direct extension of base class.

A really hope that someone would look into this (probably, in some way esoteric) problem.

Comment: So you want both Record and RecordFile to point to the same row in the database table?

Comment: Yes. And I want RecordFile to extend Record methods as well.

Comment: Assuming that one Record can have multiple RecordFiles then it is a simple one to many relation and your second approach is fine.

Comment: I thought so... And if relation is One-to-one?